# Removing trailing space in content control textbox

Tags: vba, ms-word

I work on a lot of standard lease at work. The lease template is long, but very simple. Our paralegal only needs to copy and paste client-specific information from our database to the relevant fields. But these fields are scattered all over the template doc, which means inadvertent user error is not uncommon.

I created a .dot file and add content control so that our paralegal is prompted with a dialog box and can input all the information needed all in one place. Problem is, they like to double-click the information from the source database and when pasted to the .dot fields, these always have a trailing space. How do I modify my script so all trailing spaces are automatically ignored?

My VBA code:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Caption = "Client Long-form Agreement Template"
Label1.Caption = "Site Name"
Label2.Caption = "Site Number"
Label3.Caption = "Lease Title and Date"
Label4.Caption = "Monthly Fee"
Me.TextBox4.Value = "6,500"
CommandButton1.Caption = "OK"
CommandButton2.Caption = "Cancel"

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
'Hide the userform
Hide
'Loop through the controls in the document
For Each oCC In ActiveDocument.ContentControls
If oCC.Title = "Site Name" Then oCC.Range.Text = TextBox1.Text
If oCC.Title = "Site Number" Then oCC.Range.Text = TextBox2.Text
If oCC.Title = "Lease Title and Date" Then oCC.Range.Text = TextBox3.Text
If oCC.Title = "Monthly Fee" Then oCC.Range.Text = TextBox4.Text
Next oCC
Dim oHeader As HeaderFooter
'Loop through the headers in Section 1. If there are more sections, you will also have to loop through the sections
For Each oHeader In ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Headers
'Loop through the headers in Section 1
For Each oCC In oHeader.Range.ContentControls
If oCC.Title = "Site Name (H)" Then oCC.Range.Text = TextBox1.Text
If oCC.Title = "Site Number (H)" Then oCC.Range.Text = TextBox2.Text

Next oCC
Next oHeader

'Unload the form
Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
'User has cancelled so unload the form
Unload Me

End Sub
```

I honestly haven't got a clue what to do. I'm guessing the solution is to have an if statement. But while some of the fields contain only one word, other fields may contain more than one words. So I can't just delete all spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `Trim` function removes leading spaces and trailing spaces

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [LTrim, RTrim, and Trim functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/ltrim-rtrim-and-trim-functions?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

```
If oCC.Title = "Site Name" Then oCC.Range.Text = Trim(TextBox1.Text)
```

- Please double check the last character with below, to make sure it is a space. The result should be `32`. Assumes `TextBox1` has a tailing non-printing character (maybe not a space).

```
Debug.Print Asc(Right(TextBox1.Text,1))
```

- Otherwise, you need more code lines to check the last character before removing the non-printing character. e.g. assumes the ASCII code of the character is `7`.

```
    Dim sTxt As String
    Const CHAR_ASC = 7
    sTxt = TextBox1.Text
    If Asc(Right(sTxt, 1)) = CHAR_ASC Then sTxt = Left(sTxt, Len(sTxt) - 1)
    If oCC.Title = "Site Name" Then oCC.Range.Text = sTxt
```